# Google Script automatic email function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So,

I am trying to programme a button on a spreadsheet we use at work that automatically send's an email to an employee with the date of their next review. I can programme a button with script that contains a pre-written message but I want to create a script that takes data from the spreadsheet itself to generate the content of the email.

I have tried a number of different scripts from this site and from youtube but seem to be getting nowhere so am wondering if someone can help?

This is the script I'm currently using :

```
    function sendEmail()
 { 
//FetchEmailAddress
var EmailRange = Spreadsheet.App.GetActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Email 
Harry).getRange (B2);
var EmailAddress = EmailRange.GetValues ();
//SendAlertEmail
var SubjectRange = Spreadsheet.App.GetActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Email 
Harry).getRange (E2)
var Subject = SubjectRange.GetValues
var message = 'This is your Review email!'; // Second column
var subject = Subject;
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

[And this is a screenshot of the Sheets document we use to track and plan reviews :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNGf1.png)

If anyone can help would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Email Harry");
  var emailAddress = sh.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var subject = sh.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var message = 'This is your Review email!'; 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```